# Robot Framework cant find the element via SeleniumLibrary

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I would like to click a button on google.com. But it show `Element '//input[@name="btnI"]' not visible after 5 seconds.`. Does anyone know how to do it?

I also tried to input search string first and click button, it work well.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Robot Framework Example
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Library             OperatingSystem

Suite Setup         Open Browser    https://www.google.com/   chrome
Suite Teardown      Close Browser

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    Search Web

*** Keywords ***
Click Doodle Button
    [Documentation]    Click button
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   //input[@name="btnI"]
    Click Element   //input[@name="btnI"]    

Search Web
    [Documentation]    Search Web
    Click Doodle Button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   (//input[@name="btnI"])[2]
Click Element   (//input[@name="btnI"])[2]
```

Therre are two elements the correct element is second one , use above locator